# Navigation bar with categories (and subcategories)

Tags: laravel

I need your help. I new in Laravel. 
I want to get all categories and subcategories into my navigation bar so on every page. I have a Category model. How to get all categories? Can I just using something like

```
Category::all()->get() etc.
```

in my layout, is it right to call from the layout?

Comment: yes you can use this, but better call it from controller and pass as parameter to your view (layout)

Comment: can you show how to make it using controller, should I use route?

Comment: may be this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U_0gNBN7Q7I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use view composers to pass a variable to all pages. First create a view composer in App\View\Composer;

```
    namespace App\View\Composers;
    use App\Category;
    use Illuminate\View\View;

    class InjectCategory
    {
       protected $categories;

       public function __construct(Category $categories)
       {
           $this->categories= $categories;
       }

       public function compose(View $view)
       {
           $categories= $this->categories->all();
           $view->with('categories',$categories);
       }
    }
```

Then you should add the view composer to the AppServiceProvider's boot method.

```
public function boot(Request $request)
    {

        $this->app['view']->composer(['includes.frontend.menu'], Composers\InjectCategory::class);

    }
```

Now you can use the $categories values from your menu.blade.php and include it to top of any page you want to show navigation.

Answer (score 0):

Some how when i was working on a Blog Project i also had the same issue which i solved by sharing the data with all views  which is quite easy and simple way.

in your `app/Provider/AppServiceProvider.php` file in `boot` Method add below code:

```
 public function boot()
    {
        $categories = Category::all();
        view()->share('categories', $categories);    
    }
```

and now you can access `$categories` in every view for more detail info visit this [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/views#sharing-data-with-all-views).